# Como enviar informações de um formulário sem ser redirecionado pelo action?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Olá, estou montando um formulário que pegar informações de um pedido e envia para a página processa.php, mas sempre que clico no botão para enviar (`<button type="submit" class="botao" name="botao" id="finalizarP" onclick="finalizarPedido()">FINALIZAR PEDIDO</button>`) a gente é redirecionado para a página php.

Eu queria usar o php para armazenar informações do pedido que só pode ser acessado através do link (no caso fiz um login com usuário e senha para acessar tal página).

Existe alguma maneira de evitar esse redirecionamento e fica na página index.html?

html:

```
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Pizzaria Yellow Drinks & Bebidas</title>
  </head>
 <form action="processa.php" method="POST">
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="escreveMesa" id="esMesa"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao1" id="formacao1"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao2" id="formacao2"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao3" id="formacao3"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao4" id="formacao4"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao5" id="formacao5"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao6" id="formacao6"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao7" id="formacao7"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao8" id="formacao8"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao9" id="formacao9"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao10" id="formacao10"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao11" id="formacao11"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao12" id="formacao12"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao13" id="formacao13"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao14" id="formacao14"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao15" id="formacao15"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao16" id="formacao16"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao17" id="formacao17"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao18" id="formacao18"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao19" id="formacao19"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao20" id="formacao20"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao21" id="formacao21"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="linha"/>
      <input class="escondeTabela" type="text" id="result"/>
      <center>
        <button type="submit" class="botao" name="botao" id="finalizarP" onclick="finalizarPedido()">FINALIZAR PEDIDO</button>
      </center>
     </form>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
        background: lightgray;
      }
      h1 {
        margin: 0;
      }
      h2 {
        margin: 5px;
        font-family: Helvetica;
        color: #000;
        -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
        -webkit-text-stroke-color: #fff;
      }
      h3 {
        font-size: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
      }
      h4 {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        font-size: 20px;
      }
    .botao {
        background: green;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .escondeTabela{
        display: block;
      }
     </style>
```

JavaScript:

```
      function finalizarPedido() {
          alert("Pedido realizado com sucesso!");
        }
```

Já tentei outros métodos que vi pela internet mas nenhum "enviou" as informações para a página php. Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeceria muito pois é um projeto muito importante para mim pois vai ajudar meus pais no barzinho deles.

**PS.: Comecei a mexer com html, css, javascript e php essa semana...**

**PS2.: Tem muito mais coisa no código, tipo umas 1350 linhas. Então coloquei só a parte que estou em dúvida, se precisar de tudo eu posto o resto.**

Comment: Não sei se entendi corretamente; você precisa que a página não mude, mas seja feita uma requisição em segundo plano para esse script php? Se for o caso, acredito que você precise ler sobre [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Comment: É exatamente isso! Quero usar a página php como um "servidor" para guardar os dados dos pedidos. A ideia é fazer um cardápio digital onde o cliente seleciona o que quer e o pedido chegue no balcão pela página php, mas não quero que os clientes tenham acesso a essa página (processa.php).

Comment: O `<button type="submit">` envia os dados para o servidor e carrega a resposta no contexto de navegação. Se não deseja esse comportamento use `<button type="button">` e faça o envio dos dados por meio de uma solicitação [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX). Link de [pesquisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax?tab=Votes).

Comment: ok, Vou tentar fazer dessa maneira!

Comment: Tentei de todas as formas e continuo não recebendo as informações em php... Sempre que eu faço login para acessa a página (php) da um aviso de  Undefined array key...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reformulei um pouquinho e acho que deve funcionar:

DOMContentLoaded -> Evento de quando a página estiver totalmente carregada

Submit -> Evento de quando o formulário for submetido

e.preventDefault(); -> Evento que cancela o evento principal do alvo, como ele está dentro do event submit com a variável 'e' (e) => sendo o alvo então ele cancelará o submit quando for clicado no botão

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
<title>Pizzaria Yellow Drinks & Bebidas</title>
</head>
<form id="meu_formulario" action="processa.php" method="POST">
<input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="escreveMesa" id="esMesa"/>
<input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao1" 
id="formacao1"/>
  <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao2" 
id="formacao2"/>
  <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao3" 
id="formacao3"/>
  <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao4" 
id="formacao4"/>
  <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao5" 
id="formacao5"/>
  <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao6" 
id="formacao6"/>
  <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao7" 
id="formacao7"/>
  <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao8" 
id="formacao8"/>
  <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao9" 
id="formacao9"/>
  <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao10" 
id="formacao10"/>
  <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao11" 
id="formacao11"/>
  <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao12" 
id="formacao12"/>
  <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao13" 
id="formacao13"/>
  <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao14" 
id="formacao14"/>
  <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao15" 
id="formacao15"/>
  <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao16" 
id="formacao16"/>
  <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao17" 
id="formacao17"/>
  <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao18" 
id="formacao18"/>
  <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao19" 
id="formacao19"/>
  <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao20" 
id="formacao20"/>
  <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="informacao21" 
id="formacao21"/>
  <input class="escondeTabela" type= "text" name="linha"/>
  <input class="escondeTabela" type="text" id="result"/>
  <center>
    <button type="submit" class="botao" name="botao" id="finalizarP" 
 onclick="finalizarPedido()">FINALIZAR PEDIDO</button>
  </center>
 </form> 
 <script>
  function elid(value){
    return document.getElementById(value);
   }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{
    elid("meu_formulario").addEventListener("submit", (e)=>{
      e.preventDefault(); //cancela o envio do formulário
   });
  });
  
   finalizarPedido =() =>{
    let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('escreveMesa', elid("esMesa").value);
      formData.append('informacao1', elid("formacao1").value);
      formData.append('informacao2', elid("formacao2").value);
        ....... //Continue fazendo os form datas baseado no 'name' e 'id' value

      fetch("processa.php",
          {
              body: formData,
              method: "post"
          }).then(r => r.json())
            .then(data => {
              //aqui vc coloca o retorno do servidor, ou o ser alert
              //Se vc quiser comparar os valores que vem do servidor use o 
'data'
              alert("Pedido realizado com sucesso!");
            })
   };

 </script>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Assim que eu chegar em casa vou tentar! Mas pelo que vi rapidinho pode dar certo! Obrigada pela resposta :)

Comment: Funcionou! Nem acredito kkkkk Ainda coloquei um    window.location.href=window.location.href   para recarregar a página e deixar o formulário em branco de novo!

Comment: Se te ajudou não esqueça e marcar como a resposta certa

Answer (score 1):

Adicione em sua função:

```
event.preventDefault()
```

Isso cancelará o evento sem que pare a propagação do mesmo.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Já tentei usar isso, mas os dados que coloco no formulário não "envia" para a página php, aparece esses avisos: Warning: Undefined array key "escreveMesa" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cardapio digital\processa.php on line 2

Warning: Undefined array key "informacao1" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cardapio digital\processa.php on line 3

Warning: Undefined array key "informacao2" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cardapio digital\processa.php on line 4

Answer (score -1):

Consegui uma solução provisória, usei  `echo ("<script language='JavaScript'>window.location.href='index.html';</script>");`.

Colocando isso, a página principal ficou com efeito de recarregamento.
Acho que vou deixar assim mesmo... kkkkkkk

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).